# Sub-namespace in jQuery

Tags: jquery, namespaces

I want to create a sub-namespace in jQuery. I've tried this:

```
$.fn.tx = function() {
    console.log(this);
    return this;
};

$.fn.tx.lib = function() {
    console.log(this);
    return this;
};
```

If I write,

```
$('selector').tx();
```

Firebug will show my selected DOM. But if

```
$('selector').tx.lib();
```

It shows an empty function.

I don't know why this happened. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't the correct way to namespace in jQuery.  I was confused about this at first also when I went to write my first plugin.  There's some good documentation at the [jQuery plugin authoring page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing).

In a nutshell, you want to define your namespace as you've done in your first sample:

```
$.fn.tx = function(args) {
  console.log(this);
  return this;
};
```

And then inside there you can define functions that you'd like 'namespaced', and call them as on the jQuery docs.  Hope this helps!